# Reactive data linked to handlebars helper for setting css classes

Tags: meteor

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  item1:0, 
  item2:1,
  item3:-1
}
```

I want to use the values in that object to govern the colors of some objects in the DOM. So I would like this to be reactive, such that if the data changes the colors of the objects will change as well.

I'm not sure what the most effective way to handle this is. I currently have a handlebars helper defined that maps the given values to the necessary css classes. However, it's not reactive. I could put the map into the Session.

```
Session.set('data_map',map);
```

However, in my template this causes problems. The following yields and error.

```
<button class="btn {{colorHelper Session.get('item1')}}">
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set a helper on your template:

```
Template.yourtemplatename.colorHelper = function() {
    return Session.get("data_map");
}
```

Then your html

```
<template name="yourtemplatename">
    ...

    <button class="btn {{colorHelper.item1}}">

    ...
</template>
```

You can set your `data_map` Session variable as either an object like you did & access the stuff inside using this dot notation or you can set its variable as a string and access it directly with just `{{colorHelper}}`